# Remove Columns with missing values above a threshold pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing data preprocessing and want to remove features/columns which have more than say 10% missing values.

I have made the below code:

```
df_missing=df.isna()
result=df_missing.sum()/len(df)
result

Default           0.010066
Income            0.142857
Age               0.109090
Name              0.047000
Gender            0.000000
Type of job       0.200000
Amt of credit     0.850090
Years employed    0.009003
dtype: float64
```

I want df to have columns only where there are no missing values above 10%.

**Expected output:**

df

```
Default   Name   Gender   Years employed
```

(columns where there were missing values greater than 10% are removed.)

I have tried

```
result.iloc[:,0] 
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because division of sum by length is `mean`, you can instead `df_missing.sum()/len(df)` use `df_missing.mean()`:

```
result = df.isna().mean()
```

Then filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for all rows and columns by mask:

```
df = df.loc[:,result > .1]
```

Comment: Why have you taken .mean for df.isna().mean()

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - division sum by length is mean ;)

Answer (score 1):

it should be `df = df.loc[:,result < .1]` as the user only want to keep the columns that have less than 10% of the rows missing

Answer (score 0):

pandas has built in methods for such things:

`df_clean = df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=(len(df)*.1), inplace=False)`

Or if you don't want to create an extra dataframe object you can do it inplace:

`df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=(len(df)*.1), inplace=True)`